# Get an array of specific keys from Firebase using Angularfire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have the following Firebase structure with:

A list of bakeries:

```
firebaseio.com/bakery/:id/stuffAboutTheBakery
```

And a list of bakers:

```
firebaseio.com/baker/:id/bakery/bakeryId
```

Bakers can provide bread to several bakeries so in the baker details I have an object that lists all the bakeries they supply using the bakery ID as a key and a value of true.

In my app I have a `$firebaseObject` with a baker. I want to get an array with the details of the bakeries they service. I can obviously just go to each end point but surely there is a better way. So my questions are:

1. Is this data structure what the documentation means by flat structure? Or is there a better way to structure this?
2. How do I query several specific bakeries into an array?

This is my current code:

```
self.baker = $firebaseObject(firebase.baker.child($stateParams.id));

self.baker.$loaded()
  .then(function() { 
    self.bakeries = [];
      for (var bakery in self.baker.bakeries) {
        self.bakeries.push($firebaseObject(firebase.bakery.child(bakery)));
      }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase team member here.

To answer your questions:

1 - This is *exactly* what the docs means by flat structure! What wouldn't be flat is if you put the `bakery` data underneath the `baker`. Separating the two is what we recommend.

2 - Since you have an object that stores the bakery ids for the baker you can get all the bakeries for that baker. You can synchronize that object and then for each of those bakeries you can create an array given it's id. Be careful though that you're not downloading too much data, as it will make your app slow.

I [answered a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343176/firebase-id-from-second-level-object/32353546#32353546) recently about `clients` and `invoices`. That should show you enough code to get your started.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I actually saw the other article you wrote. My issue here is that I have a many to many relationship so I can't share IDs like you suggest. Can you kindly edit with how to get an object that is linked to several specific IDs. (I obviously know I can make a request for each and get individual $firebaseObjects.I just wonder if there is a better approach.

Comment: By many to many I mean there are bakeries can be linked to many bakers and a baker supplies many different bakeries.

Comment: I added my code that I think must be improvable! :)